# Object [object Object] has no method - jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get flexslider up and running but I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider' maximizesocialmedia.wordpresslochness.com/:234
```

It looks like the most common problem with that error is jQuery is loaded twice. I have been looking and can't find where it would be loaded twice on my site. When I view the source I can't find it loaded twice and I am not seeing anything in the chrome web inspector. Could there be a different reason as to why it's not working? [Here is the site](http://maximizesocialmedia.wordpresslochness.com/)

If I need to update this post with any code please let me know.

Comment: Put the relevant code here, in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what is relevant because I am not sure where the problem is. Would you like all of the code that makes up the page?

Comment: no, your script includes and the code where you call said method should be enough. If you think you're not seeing an include that IS there, try using the find command, Ctrl+F

Comment: Is Firebug throwing an error, and what is it?  What line of code is it throwing the error on?

Comment: are you actually including flexslider? i couldnt find it loaded anywhere.

Comment: Try using the developer console in your web browser. It may help you to find the line where the error is located.

Comment: I think you worng call plugin, you have `slides.min.jquery.js` you should call `jquery.flexslider.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not loading the `flexslider` plugin in your page, try adding it in a script tag, after `jQuery`.

It's probably named `jquery.flexslider.min.js`.

Comment: That embarrassing....Thanks for the help. I'll accept the answer as soon as the time limit is up.

Comment: It happens, and it can be hard to notice when you're the one building the site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `jQuery flexslider` is not loaded. I just looked at your site and I couldn't find the javascript file related to flexslider.

Include the flexslider javascript in you page and it should work.

I also noticed that the site used [slidesjs](http://slidesjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

that console error could mean that the jquery/js for the flexslider haven't loaded so the flexslider give an error that the flexslider object for the settings is not defined as an object
i guess...